# Datatables.net ara not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, responsive

I'm using Datatables.net. I like when I refresh the page and also features a "not" responsive "". But again the browser Resize the ": shape b that's coming out like that? I want it to be the first and opening up the responsive

**Shape B:** 
[image]

I found the solution, if you have problems like me, use this script code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
  $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
     .columns.adjust()
     .responsive.recalc();
});
```

Source: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/

Comment: have u have tried in other browser's like chrome and firefox and all.

Comment: Yes i tried it all. The same problem in all

Comment: have u added bootstrap data table css file. share your code.

Comment: I opened a new page called webform1.aspx. I tested it there is no such a problem. I put the table inside the bootstrap panel. All my references are complete. Somewhere in the place I have not found yet. It's not about not showing any missing references

Comment: my html code https://jsfiddle.net/enverkoseler/j4ppovc9/